# Prefered Style Container for the Components in the DataTemplate

Tags: template, wpf, xaml

The following **XAML** is a close (tidied up) version of what I have use in my WPF application. If you have noticed there are two `Style`s applied to the same component (`Border` in this example.)

I would like to know how can I merge the 2nd `Style` into 1st to make it apply to all the `Borders` included in the `DataTemplate`.

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:myFoo}">
  <DataTemplate.Resources>
    <!-- 1) Style Applied to the Border -->
    <Style TargetType="Border">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
    </Style>
  </DataTemplate.Resources>
  <Border>
    <Grid>
      <Border>
        <!-- Guts -->
      <Border>
    </Grid>
    <Border.Style>
      <!-- 2) Style Applied to the Border -->
      <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Active}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Border.Style>
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I am familiar with the fact that 2nd `Style` will only apply to its own component unlike the 1st which will be applied to any `Border` included in the `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the two style in the DataTemplate.Resources so that it can be applied in all the Borders inside the DataTemplate. Refer the below code.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:myFoo}">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <!-- 1) Style Applied to the Border -->
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Active}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Border>
            <Grid>
                <Border>
                    <!-- Guts -->
                 </Border>
            </Grid>                
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I think he did this by design, so he can have other `Border`s without these properties.

Comment: I am surprised I have missed the most obvious. I donno why on earth I didn't think of this on the time of writing the snippet. This is literally the 2nd trigger untouched and moved to the 1st spot as it was. I must have given it a go with a typo or something and thought I donno how to do this. Thanks.